.NET Maui - option to neuter property binding
In .NET Maui I have this XAML:
        <Style x:Key="GreenLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green"/>                      
        </Style>              

       <Label Style="{StaticResource GreenLabelStyle}" 
              Text="Some text"
              TextColor="{Binding SometimesOverrideColor}"
              />

       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding OverrideColorStyle}"/>

The Label's TextColor is bound to this property:
    public Color SometimesOverrideColor
    {
        get
        {
            return OverrideColorStyle ? Colors.Pink : Colors.Green; // works, but not DRY
        }
    }

Even though I have a specified a (bound) TextColor, I want the option to say "ignore this property setting and act as though there were no explicit TextColor on the Label".  I tried returning null for SometimesOverrideColor, but that didn't work.  I want to use the value of the Label's style (i.e. green).
Obviously, I can return Colors.Green in SometimesOverrideColor, but that repeats the value specified in the style.  If I changed the style I would have to remember to update the property.
What I have in mind is like the inherit keyword in CSS.  If I could return Color.Inherit that would be great!

Is this based on some condition? If so why not create two styles and apply the style conditionally through a converter may be or whatever

@FreakyAli Yes - assume that SometimesOverrideColor can return thousands of possible Color values.  Under some circumstances I want it to return "inherit", meaning "Behave as though no TextColor was specified."

SometimesOverrideColor is a Color property? If so do you manually update it (I mean you do right?)

@CarlJ check my answer, as very basic alternative. You can make a text pink when "invalid" and "green" when valid. The only downside is if you want to mix the size from style1, the color from style2, the font from style3 and so on. But for switching between styles, this is one line in your XAML, using community toolkit maui.

I was hoping for a technique in which TextColor could be set to a value that means "ignore this setting".  The answers I've received seem to achieve the overall effect of my question by switching between multiple styles.  I guess they answer my question indirectly.  The answer is: the "inherit" feature doesn't exist.

Based on my understanding of your question I would do something to the effect of this
 <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="SometimesOverrideColor" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Pink" />
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="GreenLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
    </Style>

And then write a short converter that would conditionally apply this:

//Name this sensibly 
public abstract class WhateverColorConveter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not bool condition)
        {
            return null; // in case someone uses the converter but is a smartass
        }

        return  Application.Current.Resources.GetResource<Style>(condition ? "SometimesOverrideColor" : "GreenLabelStyle");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


GetResource is an extension I have created:
 public static T GetResource<T>(this ResourceDictionary dictionary, string key)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) && value is T resource)
            return resource;
        else
            return default;
    }

And then this would be used with your XAML code style, don't forget to add this into your resources as a static resource:

<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converters:WhateverColorConveter x:Key="WhateverColorConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>


And then use this :
<Label Style={Binding Condition, Converter={StaticResource WhateverColorConverter}}/>



I do not know how familiar you are with behaviors.
If you take for example CommunityToolkit.Maui, and check out ValidationBehavior.
You have two styles: ValidVisualState and InvalidVisualState.
Now, this behavior revolves around one boolean - IsValid. That boolean gets changed based on different sub-classes. (You can for example validate text using regex.)
Anyway, the interesting points there are two methods: UpdateStyle and UpdateSate.
And you then have
VisualStateManager.GoToState(view, isValid ? ValidVisualState : InvalidVisualState);

It doesn't have to be a bool, you know.
You can have behavior, using Style1, Style2, Style3... And so on.
And then one bound variable that plays the role of "switch".
And because it is a "style", you can change all kinds of properties, not specifically the color.
Check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/
And if nothing works out of the box, you can "get inspiration" to make your own behavior. (Notice how I did not say steal. Stealing is wrong)
